# Server request error: Failed to get metadata of cluster dev

Tags: java, spring-boot, hazelcast

I am using Hazelcast in our product but Hazelcast Management Center always throw the error

```
Server request error: Failed to get metadata of cluster dev
```

I started the Hazelcast Management Center like this

```
 java - jar hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.12.jar
```

Its starting with the following error

```
2022-01-06 23:03:53,076 [ INFO] [main] [c.h.w.c.BuildInfo]: Hazelcast Management Center 4.2021.12 (20211213 - 0c3d4fe), Jet client version: 4.5, Hazelcast client version: 4.2, embedded Jetty version: 9.4.43.v20210629
2022-01-06 23:03:55,973 [ INFO] [main] [c.h.w.c.SqlDbConfig]: Checking DB for required migrations.
2022-01-06 23:03:56,461 [ INFO] [main] [c.h.w.c.SqlDbConfig]: Number of applied DB migrations: 0.
2022-01-06 23:03:56,606 [ INFO] [main] [c.h.w.s.s.i.DisableLoginStrategy]: Login will be disabled for 5 seconds after 3 failed login attempts. For every 3 consecutive failed login attempts, disable period will be multiplied by 10.
2022-01-06 23:03:56,671 [ INFO] [main] [c.h.w.c.MetricsStorageConfig]: Initializing embedded metrics storage.
2022-01-06 23:03:59,140 [ INFO] [main] [c.h.w.s.ClusterManager]: Connecting to 1 enabled cluster(s) on startup.
2022-01-06 23:03:59,749 [ INFO] [MC-Client-dev.lifecycle-1] [c.h.w.s.MCClientManager]: MC Client connected to cluster dev.
2022-01-06 23:03:59,771 [ INFO] [MC-Client-dev.event-3] [c.h.w.s.MCClientManager]: Started communication with member: Member [127.0.0.1]:5701 - fabc704e-b8a1-4ea7-a236-cfb90706f843
2022-01-06 23:03:59,818 [ INFO] [AsyncExecutor-1] [c.h.w.s.ClusterMetadataStore]: Determined type of cluster dev as IMDG.
2022-01-06 23:03:59,817 [ERROR] [AsyncExecutor-2] [c.h.w.s.m.MemberConfigService]: com.hazelcast.webmonitor.controller.exception.OperationFailedApiException: failed to get remote config: java.security.AccessControlException: The client address [127.0.0.1]:21600 is not allowed for management task com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.management.GetMemberConfigMessageTask
com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: com.hazelcast.webmonitor.controller.exception.OperationFailedApiException: failed to get remote config: java.security.AccessControlException: The client address [127.0.0.1]:21600 is not allowed for management task com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.management.GetMemberConfigMessageTask
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2051) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.12.jar:?]
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3951) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.12.jar:?]
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3974) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.12.jar:?]
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4935) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.12.jar:?]
        at com.hazelcast.webmonitor.service.memberconfig.MemberConfigService.getMemberConfig(MemberConfigService.java:83) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.12.jar:?]
        at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
        at java.util.HashMap$KeySpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1556) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
        at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
        at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:485) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
        at com.hazelcast.webmonitor.service.memberconfig.MemberConfigService.memberStateAdded(MemberConfigService.java:78) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.12.jar:?]
        at com.hazelcast.webmonitor.service.memberconfig.MemberConfigService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8c8e9d94.invoke(<generated>) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.12.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:779) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.12.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.12.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.12.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.12.jar:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_222]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_222]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_222]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_222]
Caused by: com.hazelcast.webmonitor.controller.exception.OperationFailedApiException: failed to get remote config: java.security.AccessControlException: The client address [127.0.0.1]:21600 is not allowed for management task com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.management.GetMemberConfigMessageTask
        at com.hazelcast.webmonitor.service.OperationDispatcher.wrapException(OperationDispatcher.java:36) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.12.jar:?]
        at com.hazelcast.webmonitor.service.OperationDispatcher.executeOnMember(OperationDispatcher.java:51) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.12.jar:?]
        at com.hazelcast.webmonitor.service.memberconfig.MemberConfigService$1.load(MemberConfigService.java:63) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.12.jar:?]
        at com.hazelcast.webmonitor.service.memberconfig.MemberConfigService$1.load(MemberConfigService.java:60) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.12.jar:?]
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3529) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.12.jar:?]
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2278) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.12.jar:?]
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2155) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.12.jar:?]
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2045) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.12.jar:?]
        ... 24 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.security.AccessControlException: The client address [127.0.0.1]:21600 is not allowed for management task com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.management.GetMemberConfigMessageTask
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.returnOrThrowWithGetConventions(InvocationFuture.java:121) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.12.jar:?]
        at com.hazelcast.client.impl.spi.impl.ClientInvocationFuture.resolveAndThrowIfException(ClientInvocationFuture.java:95) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.12.jar:?]
        at com.hazelcast.client.impl.spi.impl.ClientInvocationFuture.resolveAndThrowIfException(ClientInvocationFuture.java:40) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.12.jar:?]
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture.get(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:645) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.12.jar:?]
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.DelegatingCompletableFuture.get(DelegatingCompletableFuture.java:118) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.12.jar:?]
        at com.hazelcast.webmonitor.service.OperationDispatcher.lambda$executeOnMember$1(OperationDispatcher.java:56) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.12.jar:?]
        at com.hazelcast.webmonitor.service.OperationDispatcher.wrapException(OperationDispatcher.java:34) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.12.jar:?]
        at com.hazelcast.webmonitor.service.OperationDispatcher.executeOnMember(OperationDispatcher.java:51) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.12.jar:?]
        at com.hazelcast.webmonitor.service.memberconfig.MemberConfigService$1.load(MemberConfigService.java:63) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.12.jar:?]
        at com.hazelcast.webmonitor.service.memberconfig.MemberConfigService$1.load(MemberConfigService.java:60) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.12.jar:?]
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3529) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.12.jar:?]
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2278) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.12.jar:?]
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2155) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.12.jar:?]
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2045) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.12.jar:?]
        ... 24 more
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: The client address [127.0.0.1]:21600 is not allowed for management task com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.management.GetMemberConfigMessageTask
        at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractMessageTask.run(AbstractMessageTask.java:112) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.12.jar:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
        at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:76) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.12.jar:?]
        at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:102) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.12.jar:?]
        at ------ submitted from ------.() ~[?:?]
        at com.hazelcast.internal.util.ExceptionUtil.cloneExceptionWithFixedAsyncStackTrace(ExceptionUtil.java:279) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.12.jar:?]
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.returnOrThrowWithGetConventions(InvocationFuture.java:112) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.12.jar:?]
        at com.hazelcast.client.impl.spi.impl.ClientInvocationFuture.resolveAndThrowIfException(ClientInvocationFuture.java:95) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.12.jar:?]
        at com.hazelcast.client.impl.spi.impl.ClientInvocationFuture.resolveAndThrowIfException(ClientInvocationFuture.java:40) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.12.jar:?]
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture.get(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:645) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.12.jar:?]
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.DelegatingCompletableFuture.get(DelegatingCompletableFuture.java:118) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.12.jar:?]
        at com.hazelcast.webmonitor.service.OperationDispatcher.lambda$executeOnMember$1(OperationDispatcher.java:56) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.12.jar:?]
        at com.hazelcast.webmonitor.service.OperationDispatcher.wrapException(OperationDispatcher.java:34) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.12.jar:?]
        at com.hazelcast.webmonitor.service.OperationDispatcher.executeOnMember(OperationDispatcher.java:51) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.12.jar:?]
        at com.hazelcast.webmonitor.service.memberconfig.MemberConfigService$1.load(MemberConfigService.java:63) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.12.jar:?]
        at com.hazelcast.webmonitor.service.memberconfig.MemberConfigService$1.load(MemberConfigService.java:60) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.12.jar:?]
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3529) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.12.jar:?]
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2278) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.12.jar:?]
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2155) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.12.jar:?]
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2045) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.12.jar:?]
        ... 24 more
2022-01-06 23:04:00,535 [ INFO] [main] [c.h.w.Launcher]:

Hazelcast Management Center successfully started at http://localhost:8080/
```

And i am able to login into Hazelcast Management Center GUI and created a Cluster as well .
But that cluster will give always give error
[image]

I used Springboot 2.5.7,HazelCast 4.2.2

Hazelcast server started properly

```
2022-01-06 22:07:08,627 DEBUG | Running with Spring Boot v2.5.7, Spring v5.3.13
2022-01-06 22:07:08,628  INFO | No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2022-01-06 22:07:13,252  INFO | [AciveMQ] Listener at tcp://0.0.0.0:32016
2022-01-06 22:07:13,611  WARN | Store limit is 102400 mb (current store usage is 0 mb). The data directory: /home/catalog20/POC_testing/installmp3dev/catalog/activemq-data/broker-nokia-60/KahaDB only has 4070 mb of usable space. - resetting to maximum available disk space: 4070 mb
2022-01-06 22:07:13,613  WARN | Temporary Store limit is 51200 mb (current store usage is 0 mb). The data directory: /home/catalog20/POC_testing/installmp3dev/catalog/activemq-data/broker-nokia-60 only has 4070 mb of usable space. - resetting to maximum available disk space: 4070 mb
2022-01-06 22:07:13,754  INFO | Cache members 127.0.0.1
2022-01-06 22:07:13,839  INFO | [LOCAL] [dev] [4.2.2] Interfaces is disabled, trying to pick one address from TCP-IP config addresses: [127.0.0.1]
2022-01-06 22:07:13,877  INFO | [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [4.2.2] Hazelcast 4.2.2 (20210811 - c38011e) starting at [127.0.0.1]:5701
2022-01-06 22:07:14,579  INFO | [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [4.2.2] Using TCP/IP discovery
2022-01-06 22:07:14,581  WARN | [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [4.2.2] CP Subsystem is not enabled. CP data structures will operate in UNSAFE mode! Please note that UNSAFE mode will not provide strong consistency guarantees.
2022-01-06 22:07:14,980  INFO | [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [4.2.2] Diagnostics disabled. To enable add -Dhazelcast.diagnostics.enabled=true to the JVM arguments.
2022-01-06 22:07:14,988  INFO | [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [4.2.2] [127.0.0.1]:5701 is STARTING
2022-01-06 22:07:15,020  INFO | [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [4.2.2]

Members {size:1, ver:1} [
        Member [127.0.0.1]:5701 - fabc704e-b8a1-4ea7-a236-cfb90706f843 this
]

2022-01-06 22:07:15,036  INFO | [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [4.2.2] [127.0.0.1]:5701 is STARTED
2022-01-06 22:07:16,244  INFO | Successfully acquired change log lock
2022-01-06 22:07:17,154  INFO | Reading from catpodmp3.databasechangelog
2022-01-06 22:07:17,393  INFO | Successfully released change log lock
2022-01-06 22:07:17,400  INFO | Successfully acquired change log lock
2022-01-06 22:07:17,401  WARN | Skipping auto-registration
2022-01-06 22:07:17,521  INFO | Successfully released change log lock
2022-01-06 22:07:17,654  INFO | HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-01-06 22:07:17,796  INFO | HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.32.Final
2022-01-06 22:07:18,116  INFO | HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2022-01-06 22:07:18,844  INFO | HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
2022-01-06 22:07:21,757  INFO | HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-01-06 22:07:23,124  INFO | Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-01-06 22:07:23,125  INFO | Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.55]
2022-01-06 22:07:23,902  INFO | At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2022-01-06 22:07:24,153  INFO | Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-01-06 22:07:25,123  INFO | Updating Version.
2022-01-06 22:07:25,140 DEBUG | Delete from catpodmp3.VERSION
2022-01-06 22:07:25,147 DEBUG | Insert into catpodmp3.VERSION (MAJOR_VERSION_NUMBER,MINOR_VERSION_NUMBER,MAINTENANCE_VERSION_NUMBER,RELEASE_NUMBER,LAST_UPDATE) values (19,0,0,0,current_date)
2022-01-06 22:07:25,149  INFO | classpath:db/upgrade/update-version.sql: 2 sql(s) executed.
2022-01-06 22:07:25,149  INFO | Updating System parameter 'MINIMUM SPECIAL CHARACTERS'.
2022-01-06 22:07:25,159  INFO | classpath:db/upgrade/check_sysparam_min-special-char_exists.sql: 1 sql(s) executed.
2022-01-06 22:07:25,159  INFO | System parameter 'MINIMUM SPECIAL CHARACTERS' already exists.
2022-01-06 22:07:28,036  WARN | Schema type was defined but can never be accessed, and can be safely deleted: Date
2022-01-06 22:07:28,037  WARN | Schema type was defined but can never be accessed, and can be safely deleted: Catalog
2022-01-06 22:07:28,037  WARN | Schema type was defined but can never be accessed, and can be safely deleted: CatalogEndpoint
2022-01-06 22:07:28,037  WARN | Schema type was defined but can never be accessed, and can be safely deleted: UserGroup
2022-01-06 22:07:28,037  WARN | Schema type was defined but can never be accessed, and can be safely deleted: ItemInformation
2022-01-06 22:07:28,037  WARN | Schema type was defined but can never be accessed, and can be safely deleted: TransactionParameter
2022-01-06 22:07:28,037  WARN | Schema type was defined but can never be accessed, and can be safely deleted: TransactionParameterValue
2022-01-06 22:07:28,037  WARN | Schema type was defined but can never be accessed, and can be safely deleted: Events
2022-01-06 22:07:28,037  WARN | Schema type was defined but can never be accessed, and can be safely deleted: Information
2022-01-06 22:07:28,038  WARN | Schema type was defined but can never be accessed, and can be safely deleted: YesNo
2022-01-06 22:07:28,038  WARN | Schema type was defined but can never be accessed, and can be safely deleted: ParameterParentToEmbeddedInput
2022-01-06 22:07:28,038  WARN | Schema type was defined but can never be accessed, and can be safely deleted: ParameterEmbeddedToEmbeddedInput
2022-01-06 22:07:28,038  WARN | Schema type was defined but can never be accessed, and can be safely deleted: ParameterEmbeddedToParentInput
2022-01-06 22:07:28,596  INFO | Retrying the connection!!
2022-01-06 22:07:28,597  INFO | Using existing Hazelcast instance with name [catalog] for session replication
2022-01-06 22:07:28,630  INFO | Successfully Connected!
2022-01-06 22:07:28,669  WARN | Translator Plugin Folder does not exist, no plugin loaded! dir=[]
2022-01-06 22:07:29,482  INFO | [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [4.2.2] Initializing cluster partition table arrangement...
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Can you please look into what is in the `<security>` section of your member config? Is `management-permission` enabled for the client? https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/security/native-client-security#permissions

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In previous version we have `hazelcastConfig.getManagementCenterConfig().setEnabled(monitorEnabled);` but this is not available in `4.2.2` version . Anything else i am missing?

Comment: The `management-permission` under `security` was added in version 4.2.

Comment: Something like this will work ?
`Config hazelcastConfig = new Config();
        SecurityConfig con =  new SecurityConfig();
        con.setEnabled(monitorEnabled);
        hazelcastConfig.setSecurityConfig(con);`

Comment: Is accessing Hazelcast from client is revoked for open source and added to Enterprises Edition ?
`Failed to instantiate [com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance]: Factory method 'embeddedHazelcast' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Security requires Hazelcast Enterprise Edition
`

Comment: Security is an enterprise feature. If you don't want to use it, then you have to remove the <security> section from your config, and it should be enough to set <management-center enabled="true">. If you want to use the security features, then you need a valid license.

Comment: I am doing like this 
`com.hazelcast.config.Config.getManagementCenterConfig().addTrustedInterface( monitorUrl);`   I didnt not found anything true/false

Comment: What happens if you don't configure ManagementCenterConfig explitily? Is MC still able to connect?

Comment: It worked without any issue. How this is working without ManagementCenterConfig?

Comment: MC is just a (privileged) client, so it works in the same way as any other hazelcast client instances do.